# Word that means hold a certain individual up as an inspiring example?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Word that means hold a certain individual up as an inspiring example?

I think more people identify with and _______ joker than batman these days.

Feel free to rearange the sentence if n

Comment: @YosefBaskin Idolize works thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Idolize**, American. **Idolise**, Brittish](https://www.lexico.com/definition/idolize).

> Admire, revere, or love greatly or excessively.

Metaphorically, to treat as your idol. By nature, you also *idealize/idealise* (Regard as perfect or better than in reality) to further build up your fantasy.

Answer (score 0):

I think more people identify with and *Worship/love/inspire* joker than batman these days.
If you are trying to convey this, you could use the following words :

1. Adore
2. Revere
3. Enamor